# inline video Integration issue in openx and flowplayer

Tags: flowplayer, openx

I am using following jquery live click to display ad from my openx server.

```
$('.vbox > li > img').live('click',function(){
var videourl = "http://www.indiantripadviser.com/img/video/"+$(this).data('videourl');
var videodur = parseInt($(this).data('duration'));

$('#vidHolder').show();

flowplayer("player", "dist/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
        "playlist":[
        {
            "url": videourl,
            "duration": videodur
        }
        ],
        "plugins": {
            "ova": {
                "url": "dist/swf/ova.swf",
                "autoPlay": true,
                "ads": {
                    "controls": {
                       "skipAd": {
                          "enabled": true,
                          "showAfterSeconds": 5,
                          "image": "global/images/skip.png",
                          "width": 100,
                          "height": 15
                       }
                    },
                    "servers": [
                        {
                            "type": "OpenX",
                            "apiAddress": "http://advert.visionimpact.co.in/www/delivery/fc.php"
                        }
                    ],
                    "schedule": [
                        {
                            "zone": "8",
                            "position": "pre-roll"
                        }
                    ],
                    "notice": { "type": "countdown" }
                }
            }
    },
    "canvas": {
        "backgroundColor": '#F9F9F9'
    }
});

});
```

Now my issue is, if I use the "apiAddress": "`http://advert.indiantripadviser.com/www/delivery/fc.php`" it works fine but when i change it to `"apiAddress": "http://advert.**visionimpact.co.in**/www/delivery/fc.php"` it stops delivering ads. I can't figure out where is the mistake, as I created, linked the zone and banner several times.
I am totally out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a crossdomain issue. Have you allowed

```
http://advert.**visionimpact.co.in**
```

in your crossdomain xml file?

If you are serving your ads from a different domain name than the flash player, you need to install a crossdomain.xml file in the docroot on your openX ad server to allow flash to communicate to it.

Example crossdomain xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Ref : http://code.google.com/p/openx-iab-vast/wiki/ExampleCrossdomainXML